# Particle system from material

Tags: materials, particles

I built a Material that displaces a Plane with a Noise-Texture. Then I take the Normals form the faces and dependend on that the Material sets an Image-Texture (gras on the flater parts or rock on the steeper parts).
For that desicion I use a Normal-Node compared with a Color-Ramp-Node.
I plan to use a particle system for planting gras and trees.
Is it possible to use that Material to define where the particles are alowed and where not?

Comment: Please elaborate on the first sentence it's hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I hope now it's more understandable.

Comment: You could use weight painting but I don't think there is a easy and straight forward way to do it.

Comment: Would it be possible to save the material output as an img and use that img as particle wieght texture?
So I would have to refresh it manualy every time I change somthing, but still it would save a lot of time and be accurate.

Comment: In theory you could not sure how though.